# How to include custom styles with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I would like to add my own custom CSS to my new Angular CLI app...

However I am struggling to get this to work and there is not much documentation on how this works which makes it a bit of guess work!

In the image below I have added my custom style sheet in the .angular-cli.json file as so:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "app/assets/css/styles.css"
  ],
```

This however does not work...

Kindly advise!

[image]

Comment: do you use ng serve ?

Comment: you can add the path to your index.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per your folder structure, correct path is `assets/css/styles.css` so change it in your `angular-cli.json` file as below and check it.

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "assets/css/styles.css"
],
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the path to use. I also had to stop and re-start the app for it to recognise the new location... I was just adding it and refreshing the site.

Comment: Yes! Restarting `ng serve` is what was missing for me.

Comment: where is this in angular.json in angular 6?

Comment: It is now angular.json not angular-cli.json

Comment: How do you use those style in the components? I added "my-styles.scss" in angular.json

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is to create a folder (in `src/`) call it `styles/` place your `style.css` (or SCSS and all other `_variables.scss` files) in it then amend `angular-cli.json` thus:

```
"styles": [
  "styles/styles.css"
]
```

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong with this answer... it just wasn't explained very well. Nowhere did the OP say that the folder structure had to be under assets.